# How do you name output variables for model created with the CNTK layers API?

Tags: python, cntk

I've trained a model with multiple outputs which I would like to refer to by name. The input variables can be named at construction in the API so that the evaluation code can provide data to appropriate named input variables. But in some cases, I have models with multiple scalar outputs, and right now they appear to be give some sort of programmatically constructed name that likely refers to the operation used to construct them. Is there a way to provide names for output variables during model construction? (Or even rename a specific variable after construction and prior to saving the model for later evaluation?)

Answer (score 0):

The output naming scheme has changed in the just published [Beta 8](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTk/wiki/CNTK_2_0_beta_8_Release_Notes). While it still does not allow to change the output names after creation, it provides now a consistent pattern that should work for you:

> if the function has single output, the name of output variable is the same as the function name. In case of multiple outputs, they are named as function name plus the output order as suffix, e.g. `Foo.1`, `Foo.2`, etc.